# Understanding the proof that the conditional distribution of a Gaussian random variable is linear in the conditioning Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, and $Y:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be random variables such that $(X,Y)$ is a Gaussian random vector.

Then there exists $a,b_1, \dots, b_k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$P(X\in dx| Y=y)=N(a+\sum b_k y_k, \sigma^2)$$ where $Z \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ is a Gaussian independent of Y from a previous theorem.

The proof below is from Rene Schilling. I have two questions regarding the proof.

First, how do we get $E(g(Y)e^{i\xi (a+\sum b_k Y_k + Z}))=\int g(y) E(e^{i\xi (a+\sum b_k y_k + Z}))P(Y\in dy)$ from the fact that $Z $ and $Y$ are independent?

Second, I cannot understand the final identity. Why does the identity $E(g(Y) \int e^{i\xi x} P(X\in dx|Y) = \int g(y) E(e^{i\xi (a+\sum b_k y_k + Z))}) P(Y\in dy)$ for any bounded measurable $g$ imply that $\int e^{i\xi x} P(X\in dx|Y=y) = E(e^{i\xi (a+\sum b_k y_k + Z)})$?

I would greatly appreciate a rigorous explanation to these details.

[image]

Comment: For your first question, use the property that if $g: \mathbb R^2 \mapsto \mathbb R$ satisfies $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |g(x,y)|\, \mathrm dF(x,y) < \infty$ then $E[g(X,Y)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,y) \, \mathrm dF(x,y)$ in a Stieltjes form. And that $\mathrm dF(x,y) = f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$. Are these things facts to you? If so, you use independence on $f(x,y)$ and you are done.

Comment: In the notation above, $\mathrm dF(x,y) = \mathbb P(X\in \mathrm dx, Y \in \mathrm dy)$.

Comment: @Therkel Yes I am aware of that but this seems to be more general, that is, applies to cases without densities wrt Lebesgue measure. I was looking for a more general result.

Comment: Hmm okay. What if you did the above in Lebesgue-Stieltjes form?

Comment: For your second question, can it be seen from the first result's expectation on integral form (from your picture)? It looks like you have something on the form $\int g(y) h_1(X,y)\mathbb P(Y\in \mathrm dy) = \int g(y) h_2(Z,y)\mathbb P(Y\in \mathrm dy)$ so you get $h_1(X,y)=h_2(Z,y)$. I think it looks like the identity. I know you ask for rigor and I would probably have flailed some informal argument about if a property of $E[X\mid Y=y]$ holds then so does $E[X\mid Y]$, so I can't help much more there.

Answer (score 1):

The identity in your first question follows from the fact that
$$ \mathbb{E}[f(X)g(Y)] = \mathbb{E}[f(X)]\cdot\mathbb{E}[g(Y)] $$
which can be seen by conditioning on one of the variables (tower property) and then pulling out the independent factor (or the measurable factor).

In your context this means
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[g(Y)e^{i\xi(a+\sum b_kY_k})e^{i\xi Z}] &= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[g(Y)e^{i\xi(a+\sum b_kY_k)}e^{i\xi Z} \mid Z]] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[e^{i\xi Z}\mathbb{E}[g(Y)e^{i\xi(a+\sum b_kY_k)}\mid Z]] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[e^{i\xi Z}]\mathbb{E}[g(Y)e^{i\xi(a+\sum b_kY_k)}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[e^{i\xi Z}] \int g(y)e^{i\xi(a+\sum b_ky_k)}\mathbb{P}(Y\in\mathrm{d}y) \\
&= \int g(y)\mathbb{E}[e^{i\xi(a+\sum b_ky_k)}e^{i\xi Z}]\mathbb{P}(Y\in\mathrm{d}y)
\end{align}

The final identity (from your second question) follows from the fact that
$$ \int f(x)g(x)\mu(\mathrm{d}x) = 0 \quad\forall g \implies f \equiv0 \quad \mu\text{-a.e.} $$
This is sometimes called the [fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations). Intuitively you can choose $g$ positive in a region where $f$ is non-zero and then show that the integral on the left hand side can't be zero.